# Validating Text Areas

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

All my other form elements validate BUT my text area. Thoughts onto maybe why with the following code?

```
<?php $attributes = array('cols' => '30', 'rows' => '5', 'id' => 'article', 'class' => 'required') ?>
 <div>
     <?php echo form_textarea('article', '', $attributes); ?>  
 </div>
```

EDIT:
I'm using the jQuery validation class.

```
<div class="section _100">
<label for="article">Article</label>   
    <div>
        <textarea name="article" cols="40" rows="10" Array></textarea>  
    </div>
</div>
```

SO now I"m wondering why its showing that Array like that when it should be finishing putting the attributes like the class part.

Comment: Please post your validation rules and logic.

Comment: oops sorry this was for jquery

Comment: Then post your *actual* HTML, and whatever jQuery validation logic you're using. It's impossible to say what the problem is with the code you posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass array of attributes, then it should be the only `form_textarea` function. Try this:

```
<?php $attributes = array('name' => 'article', 'cols' => '30', 'rows' => '5', 'id' => 'article', 'class' => 'required') ?>
<div>
    <?php echo form_textarea($attributes); ?>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Per the [Form_helper documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html), you can generate a `textarea` by passing a name and attribute value as two arguments *or* by passing all your attributes as an array as a single argument.

Notice in your code, you have a 3rd argument. That is reserved for additional data, like JavaScript. It's just appended within the `textarea` tag as a string - which is why you're seeing `Array`.

Create your `textarea` like this, but including your name in the `$attributes` array:

```
$attributes = array(
    'name' => 'article', 
    'cols' => '30',
    'rows' => '5', 
    'id' => 'article', 
    'class' => 'required'
);

echo form_textarea($attributes);
```